# finding the posterior distribution of theta

Tags: probability-distributions

Let $Y$ be the sum of $n$ independent observations frm a $pois(\theta)$ distribution.

Further let the prior distribution for $(\theta)$ be $\gamma(\alpha,\beta)$.

I need to find the posterior distribution of $\theta$, given that $Y=y$

AND find a point estimate of $\theta$ given this value of y.

Can someone please help me to do this?

Completely stuck on how i would do this, but im guessing that a point estimate is the mean of the distribution, how would i actually find this?

Comment: Got something from my answer?

Answer (score 2):

By definition,
$$P[Y=y,\theta\in\mathrm dx]=\mathrm e^{-nx}\frac{(nx)^y}{y!}\beta^{\alpha}\Gamma(\alpha)^{-1}x^{\alpha-1}\mathrm e^{-\beta x}\mathbf 1_{x\gt0}\mathrm dx.
$$
Hence,
$$
P[\theta\in\mathrm dx\mid Y=y]\propto\mathrm e^{-(n+\beta)x}x^{y+\alpha-1}\mathbf 1_{x\gt0}\mathrm dx.
$$
Thus, conditionally on $Y=y$, the distribution of $\theta$ is $\gamma(\alpha+y,\beta+n)$. In particular,
$$
E[\theta\mid Y=y]=\frac{\alpha+y}{\beta+n}.
$$